Efficient way to compute the chromatic polynomial of the given graph.

Find the chromatic polynomial of the following graph:


Label the vertices $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Let $e=23$. Then with the Deletion-Contraction Formula,
for $P_{G/e}(x)$, it is  and $$3\ \text{colors}: 2x(x-1)(x-2)\ [13,125\ \text{same}] $$ $$4\ \text{colors}: 4x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\ [14,45,24,25\ \text{same}]$$ $$5\ \text{colors}: x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$$
By adding all these possibilities, we have $$P_{G/e}(x)=x^5-6x^4+13x^3-12x^2+4x.$$
For $P_{G-e}(x)$, it is 
and  $$3\ \text{colors}: 2x(x-1)(x-2)\ [12,34,25\ \text{or}\ 13,46,25]$$
$$4\ \text{colors}: 11x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$ $$\text{same}: 13,25\ 13,24\ 13,26\ 13,46\ 16,24\ 16,25\ 16,34\ 26,34\ 26,34\ 25,34\ 25,46\ 246$$ $$5\ \text{colors}: 7x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\ [\text{same}: 13\ 16\ 24\ 25\ 26\ 34\ 46]$$
$$6\ \text{colors}: x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$$
By adding all these possibilities, we have $$P_{G-e}(x)=x^6-8x^5+26x^4-43x^3+36x^2-12x.$$
Finally, $$P_G(x)=P_{G-e}(x)-P_{G/e}(x)=x^6-9x^5+32x^4-56x^3+48x^2-16x.$$
My solution is very complicated, I wonder whether there is an easier way to compute the chromatic polynomial?

By thinking of $G$ as being obtained via a 2-clique-sum of $K_3$ and $K_3$ and then a 2-clique-sum of the result with $K_3$ and then a 2-clique-sum of the result with $K_3$, you can compute
\begin{align}
P(G,x) 
&= \frac{P(K_3,x) P(K_3,x)}{x(x-1)}\cdot\frac{P(K_3,x)}{x(x-1)}\cdot\frac{P(K_3,x)}{x(x-1)} \\
&= \frac{P(K_3,x)^4}{x^3(x-1)^3} \\
&= \frac{(x(x-1)(x-2))^4}{x^3(x-1)^3}\\
&= x (x-1) (x-2)^4 \\
&= x^6 - 9 x^5 + 32 x^4 - 56 x^3 + 48 x^2 - 16 x.
\end{align}
This computation appears in the 1997 movie Good Will Hunting.
